# How to change the position of an object Swift SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I've two objects in one SceneKit. One is the Earth and the other is the Moon. Both of them are positioned at x:0, y:0, z:0 and are overlapping. How should I change the coordinates of the Moon so it's around the Earth?

Here the code:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scene = SCNScene()

        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()

        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y:0, z:10)

        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light?.type = .directional
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y:0, z:2)

        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

        let stars = SCNParticleSystem(named: "StarsParticles.scnp", inDirectory: nil)!
        scene.rootNode.addParticleSystem(stars)

        let moonNode = MoonNode()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(moonNode)

        let sceneview = self.view as! SCNView
        sceneview.scene = scene

        let earthNode = EarthNode()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(earthNode)

        let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView
        sceneView.scene = scene

        sceneView.showsStatistics = false
        sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your view controller a `SCNSceneRendererDelegate`, and implement the delegate method `renderer:willRenderScene` which gives you a `time`. Based on that `time`, you can set something like this:

```
moonNode.position = SCNVector3(r * cos(Float(time), r * sin(Float(time)), 0)
```

where `r` is the radius of your Earth node - if you don't know this at compile time, just include something like this above that line:

```
let r = length(float3(earthNode.boundingBox.max) - float3(earthNode.boundingBox.min))
```

this won't quite be exact for the code I included which causes a rotation in the xy plane but it will at least give you the right order of magnitude for `r`. If you get an error that it can't find float3 or length, try and `import simd`.

Let me know if you have any issues with this, as I typed this up from memory.

More info in documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerendererdelegate/1523483-renderer

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using `simdPivot` instance property.

```
var simdPivot: simd_float4x4 { get set }
```

Here's a code for testing:

```
import SceneKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scene = SCNScene()
        let action = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotate(by: .pi, 
                                                          around: SCNVector3(0,1,0), 
                                                        duration: 1))

        let earthNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 3.57))
        earthNode.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(earthNode)

        let moonNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.15))
        moonNode.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.yellow
        moonNode.simdPivot.columns.3.x = 5
        moonNode.runAction(action)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(moonNode)

        let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView
        sceneView.scene = scene

        sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    }
}
```

[image]